# Custom data structures for directx buffers

Tags: directx, buffer, structure, directx-11, vertex

Do I need to use the DirectXMath structures (XMFLOAT3, XMFLOAT4, XMMATRIX, XMFLOAT4X4, etc.) when I am setting the data for the vertex and constant buffers for a directx application. I have my own Vector3 and Matrix structures and would prefer to use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use DirectXMath.  All you need to do is ensure that the data you write matches the standard (IEEE-754) floating point layout (or whatever other format you have specified).  For vector types, just ensure that the elements are in contiguous memory.